# Google Chart Pie Chart Offset for all data

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Hi I want all the slices in a Google Pie Chart should be offset,
I have an example which offset slices with hardcoded. But I need all the slices should be offset to a specific value.

The example I have is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
          ['Assamese', 13], ['Bengali', 83], ['Bodo', 1.4],
          ['Dogri', 2.3], ['Gujarati', 46], ['Hindi', 300],
          ['Kannada', 38], ['Kashmiri', 5.5], ['Konkani', 5],
          ['Maithili', 20], ['Malayalam', 33], ['Manipuri', 1.5],
          ['Marathi', 72], ['Nepali', 2.9], ['Oriya', 33],
          ['Punjabi', 29], ['Sanskrit', 0.01], ['Santhali', 6.5],
          ['Sindhi', 2.5], ['Tamil', 61], ['Telugu', 74], ['Urdu', 52]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Indian Language Use',
          legend: 'none',
          pieSliceText: 'label',
          slices: {  4: {offset: 0.2},
                    12: {offset: 0.3},
                    14: {offset: 0.4},
                    15: {offset: 0.5},
          },
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just traverse all rows in your data and add to options the slice object for that row

Comment: Do you want the slices to all have the same offset?  If not, how should the offset be determined?

Comment: I want all the pie should have same offset, without hardcoding the pies like 4: {offset: 0.2},2: {offset: 0.3},...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i = 0;i < data.getNumberOfRows();i++){
     offsetObj[i] = {offset:0.4};
}
```

This is the solution to populate a object like {4: {offset: 0.4}, 12: {offset: 0.4},         14: {offset: 0.4},15: {offset: 0.4},}